# Extract Values from Formatted Text

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

Is there an easy way to extract variables from a text file?

E.g. given the output from `ab`:

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1638069 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking bar (be patient)
Finished 1206 requests


Server Software:        Jetty(9.0.z-SNAPSHOT)
Server Hostname:        bar
Server Port:            5500

Document Path:          /foo/1
Document Length:        148 bytes

Concurrency Level:      15
Time taken for tests:   30.041 seconds
Complete requests:      1206
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      359686 bytes
HTML transferred:       178636 bytes
Requests per second:    40.15 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       373.643 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       24.910 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          11.69 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       47  108  36.0     98     328
Processing:    73  264 782.5    150    7951
Waiting:       73  255 721.5    148    7886
Total:        129  371 783.5    259    8039

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    259
  66%    293
  75%    324
  80%    340
  90%    413
  95%    525
  98%    683
  99%   6421
 100%   8039 (longest request)
```

I'd like to extract values (matching `name: value`, see example below) and assign them to variables in one step. (I know that `ab` can export some data to csv but the rest is only available as formatted text.)

The best I've found so far is:

```
path=$(cat text|grep 'Document Path:'|awk -F: '{ split($2, z, " "); print z[1]}')
total=$(cat text|grep 'Total transferred:'|awk -F: '{ split($2, z, " "); print z[1]}')
#[...]
```

But this seems to be a bit repetitive and *awk*ward - is there an easier way or a tool that's better suited for this job?

Comment: extract what values ?

Comment: Potentially all of them.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make it specific. What values do you want? What is a "value"? Is `ApacheBench` a value? Is `50%`? Or should it be `50`? Show us a specific example and the output you would like to see. As it stands, this is just too broad. And yes, of course there are easy ways to do this but it all depends on what you want to extract.

Comment: @terdon I did include samples for the values - see path and total.

Comment: Yes, but those are just two. I think maybe you mean that you want all strings that end is colons (`foo:`) to be variable names. Is that correct?

Comment: @terdon OK, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look for all lines that have 1-4 words and then a `:`, replace the spaces between the words with underscores and print them as `variable=value` pairs. You can then pass the entire thing through `eval` to set them. For example:

```
$ awk -F': *' '/^(\S+\s*){1,4}:/{gsub(/ /,"_",$1);print $1"=\""$2"\""}' file
Server_Software="Jetty(9.0.z-SNAPSHOT)"
Server_Hostname="bar"
Server_Port="5500"
Document_Path="/foo/1"
Document_Length="148 bytes"
Concurrency_Level="15"
Time_taken_for_tests="30.041 seconds"
Complete_requests="1206"
Failed_requests="0"
Total_transferred="359686 bytes"
HTML_transferred="178636 bytes"
Requests_per_second="40.15 [#/sec] (mean)"
Time_per_request="373.643 [ms] (mean)"
Time_per_request="24.910 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)"
Transfer_rate="11.69 [Kbytes/sec] received"
Connect="47  108  36.0     98     328"
Processing="73  264 782.5    150    7951"
Waiting="73  255 721.5    148    7886"
Total="129  371 783.5    259    8039"
```

The `-F': *` sets the field separator to `:` followed by 0 or more spaces. The script then checks whether this line matches 1 to 4 occurrences of a string of non-space characters ("words") followed by 0 or more spaces and then a `:`. I use 4 because of this line:

```
Time taken for tests:   30.041 seconds
```

Then, for lines that match, replace all spaces in the first field with underscores (`gsub(/ /,"_",$1)`), then print the first field, an `=` and the second field quoted. Because bare strings need to be quoted for `awk` to print them, in order to print a quoted `$2`, the quotes need to be escaped: `" \""`.

If that produces the output you want, you can now use `eval` to read the variables:

```
$ eval $(awk -F': *' '/^(\S+\s*){1,4}:/{gsub(/ /,"_",$1);print $1"=\""$2"\""}' file)
$ echo $Transfer_rate 
11.69 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

Or, just source it:

```
. <(awk -F': *' '/^(\S+\s*){1,4}:/{gsub(/ /,"_",$1);print $1"=\""$2"\""}' file)
```

---

**Important**: This can be dangerous. `eval` or sourcing the file will simply execute any code you give it. It will not check whether it is dangerous. If the `awk` script returns something dangerous like `rm ~/*` for some reason, then `eval` will happily run it. So, always check what output you get before running the above. This is also the case for the accepted answer. It is always dangerous to blindly execute code returned by another program.

---

The above will work for GNU `awk` but not for simpler `awk` implementatins. If it doesn't work on your system, try this instead:

```
. <(awk -F': *' '/.*\s*:   *:/{gsub(/ /,"_",$1);print $1"=\""$2"\""}' file)
```

Comment: That's a neat solution. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Do I need a special version of `awk` for this? I get no output with your sample.

Comment: It works with `awk -F': *' '(NF == 2) && ($1 ~ /^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$/) {gsub(/ /,"_",$1);print $1"=\""$2"\""}'` though.

Comment: @laktak there shouldn't be any output when you `. $(awk ...)` or `eval $(awk ...)`. Does the `awk` command by itself return anything? I mean just `awk -F': *' '/^(\S+\s*){1,4}:/{gsub(/ /,"_",$1);print $1"=\""$2"\""}' file`. If not, please ping me (`@terdon`) in [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) and we can figure it out.

Comment: No, `awk -F': *' '/^(\S+\s*){1,4}:/{gsub(/ /,"_",$1);print $1"=\""$2"\""}' file` gives me no ouput (Ubuntu 15.10)

Comment: @laktak sorry, I'm on mobile so I can't test and can't really chat. Try replacing the `\S+` with `[^ +]`. I don't see why it wouldn't work on an Ubuntu system though. Could you have spaces at the beginning of the line?

Comment: Nope. Can't say what's wrong with it. Probably the awk version. `egrep '^(\S+\s*){1,4}:' file` shows the correct output. With `awk` it doesn't work on OS X either.

Comment: @laktak yes, `grep -E` (`egrep` is deprecated) will work. OSX `awk` won't since it's not GNU awk. I have no idea why it wouldn't work for you on Ubuntu which does use GNU awk. I just tried on an Ubuntu VM and it worked as expected. Anyway, see updated answer for a more portable solution.

Answer (score 4):

I generally use the following pattern:

```
. <(
    awk 'BEGIN{print "shellvarname=\"value\""}'
)
```

This uses `awk` to generate some statements that would work in the shells variable assignment syntax. This result is sourced (`.`).

In your specific request, this would be an option:

```
. <(
    awk -F': *' '
      /Document Path/{printf "%s=\"%s\"\n", "path", $2}
      /Total transferred/{printf "%s=\"%s\"\n", "total", $2}
    ' file
)
```

or a bit shorter

```
. <(
    awk '
      /Document Path/{printf "%s=\"%s\"\n", "path", $3}
      /Total transferred/{printf "%s=\"%s\"\n", "total", $3}
    ' file
)
```

Comment: `. <( command )` is an interesting [hack](http://paulgraham.com/gba.html) and I can think of occasions where it would be very useful.  I think parsing `ab`'s formatted-for-display output this way is probably a very fragile solution, though.